# How to parse string by best way and get just necessary parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

I am writing an web application. I am getting information as string at UI level using server API . Such response from server side is single string. Structure of these strings is following:

> Response (**{numberParam}** points)

It is always constant. Examples of getting strings:

`Response (76 points)`

`Response (5193 points)`

`Response (4 points)`

`Response (21 points)`

**I need retrieve only value of this numeric parameter from getting string**.

I should not use any external libraries and frameworks. Only native JavaScript.

I will be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regular expressions, which are perfect for matching patterns like this. Here is a regular expression used to split the input string into parts split by one or more non-digit characters (`\D+`) so that the resultant array looks like `['','76','']`, and you can select position 1 (`[1]`) from that array.

```
var str = "Response (76 points)"

var num = str.split(/\D+/)[1]
console.log(num)
```

Alternatively, you could replace all non numeric characters with nothing...

```
var num = str.replace(/\D/g,'')
console.log(num)
```

Or match the first chain of numeric characters...

```
var num = str.match(/\d+/)[0]
console.log(num)
```

Or possibly the most useful, is to split by one or more non-word characters (`\W+`) which gives an array of words, and then select the part you want. I like this, as it is able to retrieve other meaningful information from error messages, and can be applied to many different error messages and situations...

```
var parts = str.split(/\W+/)
// parts is: [ 'Response', '76', 'points', '' ]
var num = parts[1]
console.log(num)
```

Comment: You had a solution. Why did you feel the need to copy paste from my answer ?

Comment: @dystroy I did not, I typed with my own fingers. I answered originally before you, with a very similar concept. Your answer focuses on efficiency, and handling the matched number. Mine focuses on regex, and how it can be used in different ways. I am trying to reveal something of the power and versatility of regex, as I feel that it might help Alex to solve this, and other similar problems.

Answer (score 4):

If your string is always like that then you can simply do

```
var num = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
```

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I know, but it feels hacky parsing the string representation of the array. It isn't clearer and probaly is (marginally) slower. The `,10` could also very probably be removed but is safer.

Comment: To be safe: `parseInt(str.match(/\d+/) || [], 10)`.

Comment: To be unsafe : `parseInt(str.match(/\d+/))` :)

Comment: Excuse me, for what purpose call `parseInt()` method? Can I use just `domainCountry.match(/\d+/)[0]`? How bad is it? It is work properly.

Comment: parseInt gives you the value as a number. If a string is enough for you, don't parse it.